# KeyEvent listener: mapping physical keyboard to onscreen keyboard

Tags: java, swing, javafx, awt

I have an assignment to create a GUI with a keyboard and text area. Conceptually, the user would type on the physical keyboard and the respective key would change background on screen to reflect that key press. Pressing the onscreen keys yields no behaviour so I don't need to implement `keyTyped(...)` (I think).

For brevity and as per SO's axiomatic policies, here's some relevant code (let me know if there's something to add)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ButtonInPane extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
  // input
  String input;
  //context
  JLabel context1, context2;
  // default color
  Color defaultColor = new JButton().getBackground();
  // main rows of keys
  public String rowOne[] = {
      "~",
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6",
      "7",
      "8",
      "9",
      "0",
      "-",
      "+",
      "h"
  };
  public String rowTwo[] = {
      "Tab",
      "Q",
      "W",
      "E",
      "R",
      "T",
      "Y",
      "U",
      "I",
      "O",
      "P",
      "[",
      "]",
      "\\"
  };
  public String rowThree[] = {
      "Caps",
      "A",
      "S",
      "D",
      "F",
      "G",
      "H",
      "J",
      "K",
      "L",
      ":",
      "'",
      "Enter"
  };
  public String rowFour[] = {
      "Shift",
      "Z",
      "X",
      "C",
      "V",
      "B",
      "N",
      "M",
      ",",
      ".",
      "?",
      "   ^"
  };
  public String rowFive[] = {
      "       ",
      "<",
      "v",
      ">"
  };
  /**
   * Account for chars with no shift: Program toggles Shift key, meaning if a
   * user clicks on it, all keys will be toggled to their respective shift
   * value. The user can tap the shift key again to change back to regular
   * value
   */
  public String shiftless[] = {
      "1",
      "2",
      "3",
      "4",
      "5",
      "6",
      "7",
      "8",
      "9",
      "0",
      "-",
      "=",
      "q",
      "w",
      "e",
      "r",
      "t",
      "y",
      "u",
      "i",
      "o",
      "p",
      "[",
      "]",
      "\\",
      "a",
      "s",
      "d",
      "f",
      "g",
      "h",
      "j",
      "k",
      "l",
      ";",
      "z",
      "x",
      "c",
      "v",
      "b",
      "n",
      "m",
      ",",
      ".",
      "/"
  };
  // Account for special chars
  public String specialChars[] = {
      "~",
      "-",
      "+",
      "[",
      "]",
      "\\",
      ";",
      ".",
      "?"
  };

  // declare rows of buttons
  public JButton buttons_rowOne[], buttons_rowTwo[], buttons_rowThree[], buttons_rowFour[], buttons_rowFive[];
  private JTextArea body;
  private JPanel top;
  private JPanel middle;
  private JPanel bottom;
  private JPanel contextBox;

  // ctor
  public ButtonInPane() {
      super("Typing Tutor");
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setResizable(false);
      this.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
      this.setLocation(50, 50);
      this.setVisible(true);
      __init__();
  }

  public void __init__layout(JPanel top, JPanel middle, JPanel bottom, JPanel contextBox) {
      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
      add(contextBox);
      add(middle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
      add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  }

  public void __init__body() {
      body = new JTextArea();
      body.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 150));
      body.addKeyListener(this);
  }

  public void __init__panels() {
      context1 = new JLabel("Type some text using your keyboard. " +
          "The keys you press will be highlighed and the text will be displayed.");
      context2 = new JLabel("\nNote: Clicking the buttons with your mouse will not perform any action.");
      context1.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14));
      context2.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14));
      top = new JPanel();
      top.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
      middle = new JPanel();
      bottom = new JPanel();
      contextBox = new JPanel();
      __init__layout(top, middle, bottom, contextBox);
      top.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
      top.add(context1);
      top.add(context2);
      middle.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      middle.add(body, BorderLayout.WEST);
      middle.add(body, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  }

  public void __init__() {
      // text area
      __init__body();
      // panels for layout
      __init__panels();
      pack();
      // get length of row strings
      int length_rowOne = rowOne.length;
      int length_rowTwo = rowTwo.length;
      int length_rowThree = rowThree.length;
      int length_rowFour = rowFour.length;
      int length_rowFive = rowFive.length;
      // create array for each row of buttons
      buttons_rowOne = new JButton[length_rowOne];
      buttons_rowTwo = new JButton[length_rowTwo];
      buttons_rowThree = new JButton[length_rowThree];
      buttons_rowFour = new JButton[length_rowFour];
      buttons_rowFive = new JButton[length_rowFive];
      // create panel for each row of buttons
      JPanel r1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowOne));
      JPanel r2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowTwo));
      JPanel r3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowThree));
      JPanel r4 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowFour));
      JPanel r5 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowFive));
      // draw out the rows of buttons
      draw(r1, length_rowOne, r2, length_rowTwo, r3, length_rowThree, r4, length_rowFour, r5, length_rowFive);

  }

  // draw rows of buttons
  public void draw(JPanel r1, int s1, JPanel r2, int s2, JPanel r3, int s3, JPanel r4, int s4, JPanel r5, int s5) {
      for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
          JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowOne[i]);
          currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
          buttons_rowOne[i] = currentButton;
          r1.add(buttons_rowOne[i]);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < s2; i++) {
          JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowTwo[i]);
          currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
          buttons_rowTwo[i] = currentButton;
          r2.add(buttons_rowTwo[i]);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < s3; i++) {
          JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowThree[i]);
          currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
          buttons_rowThree[i] = currentButton;
          r3.add(buttons_rowThree[i]);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < s4; i++) {
          JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowFour[i]);
          currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
          buttons_rowFour[i] = currentButton;
          r4.add(buttons_rowFour[i]);
      }
      for (int i = 0; i < s5; i++) {
          JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowFive[i]);
          // account for space bar
          if (i == 1) {
              currentButton = new JButton(rowFive[i]);
              currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 10));
              currentButton.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 100);
              buttons_rowFive[i] = currentButton;
          } else {
              currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
              buttons_rowFive[i] = currentButton;
          }
          r5.add(buttons_rowFive[i]);
      }
      bottom.add(r1);
      bottom.add(r2);
      bottom.add(r3);
      bottom.add(r4);
      bottom.add(r5);
  } // !draw(...)
  // called when a button is pressed

  @Override
  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent press) {
    Object current = press.getSource();
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
      if (current.toString() == rowOne[i]) {
        buttons_rowOne[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        repaint();
      } else if (current.toString() == rowTwo[i]) {
        buttons_rowTwo[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        repaint();
      } else if (current.toString() == rowThree[i]) {
        buttons_rowThree[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        repaint();
      } else if (current.toString() == rowFour[i]) {
        buttons_rowFour[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        repaint();
      } else if (current.toString() == rowFive[i]) {
        buttons_rowFive[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        repaint();
      }
    }
  } // !keyPressed(...)
  // called when a button is released

  @Override
  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent release) {
    Object current = release.getSource();
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
      if (current.toString() == rowOne[i]) {
        buttons_rowOne[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
        repaint();
      } else if (current.toString() == rowTwo[i]) {
        buttons_rowTwo[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
        repaint();
      } else if (current.toString() == rowThree[i]) {
        buttons_rowThree[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
        repaint();
      } else if (current.toString() == rowFour[i]) {
        buttons_rowFour[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
        repaint();
      } else if (current.toString() == rowFive[i]) {
        buttons_rowFive[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
        repaint();
      }
    }
  } // !keyReleased(...)

  @Override
  public void keyTyped(KeyEvent typed) {
      // Object current = typed.getSource().toString();
      // StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      // for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
      //   if (current == rowOne[i]) {
      //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
      //     body.append(sb.toString());
      //   } else if (current == rowTwo[i]) {
      //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
      //     body.append(sb.toString());
      //   } else if (current == rowThree[i]) {
      //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
      //     body.append(sb.toString());
      //   } else if (current == rowFour[i]) {
      //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
      //     body.append(sb.toString());
      //   } else if (current == rowFive[i]) {
      //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
      //     body.append(sb.toString());
      //   }
      // }      
  }
  // main method
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      new ButtonInPane();
  } // !main method

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 999;
} // !main class
```

How do I map the physicals key pressed with the on screen keyboard with KeyEvent?

---

Edit:

Full code

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ButtonInPane extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
 // input
 String input;
 //context
 JLabel context1, context2;
 // default color
 Color defaultColor = new JButton().getBackground();
 // main rows of keys
 public String rowOne[] = {
  "~",
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "4",
  "5",
  "6",
  "7",
  "8",
  "9",
  "0",
  "-",
  "+",
  "h"
 };
 public String rowTwo[] = {
  "Tab",
  "Q",
  "W",
  "E",
  "R",
  "T",
  "Y",
  "U",
  "I",
  "O",
  "P",
  "[",
  "]",
  "\\"
 };
 public String rowThree[] = {
  "Caps",
  "A",
  "S",
  "D",
  "F",
  "G",
  "H",
  "J",
  "K",
  "L",
  ":",
  "'",
  "Enter"
 };
 public String rowFour[] = {
  "Shift",
  "Z",
  "X",
  "C",
  "V",
  "B",
  "N",
  "M",
  ",",
  ".",
  "?",
  "   ^"
 };
 public String rowFive[] = {
  "       ",
  "<",
  "v",
  ">"
 };
 /**
  * Account for chars with no shift: Program toggles Shift key, meaning if a
  * user clicks on it, all keys will be toggled to their respective shift
  * value. The user can tap the shift key again to change back to regular
  * value
  */
 public String shiftless[] = {
  "1",
  "2",
  "3",
  "4",
  "5",
  "6",
  "7",
  "8",
  "9",
  "0",
  "-",
  "=",
  "q",
  "w",
  "e",
  "r",
  "t",
  "y",
  "u",
  "i",
  "o",
  "p",
  "[",
  "]",
  "\\",
  "a",
  "s",
  "d",
  "f",
  "g",
  "h",
  "j",
  "k",
  "l",
  ";",
  "z",
  "x",
  "c",
  "v",
  "b",
  "n",
  "m",
  ",",
  ".",
  "/"
 };
 // Account for special chars
 public String specialChars[] = {
  "~",
  "-",
  "+",
  "[",
  "]",
  "\\",
  ";",
  ".",
  "?"
 };

 // declare rows of buttons
 public JButton buttons_rowOne[], buttons_rowTwo[], buttons_rowThree[], buttons_rowFour[], buttons_rowFive[];
 private JTextArea body;
 private JPanel top;
 private JPanel middle;
 private JPanel bottom;
 private JPanel contextBox;

 // ctor
 public ButtonInPane() {
  super("Typing Tutor");
  this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  this.setResizable(false);
  this.getContentPane().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 600));
  this.setLocation(50, 50);
  this.setVisible(true);
  __init__();
 }

 public void __init__layout(JPanel top, JPanel middle, JPanel bottom, JPanel contextBox) {
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
  add(contextBox);
  add(middle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 }

 public void __init__body() {
  body = new JTextArea();
  body.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 150));
  body.addKeyListener(this);
 }

 public void __init__panels() {
  context1 = new JLabel("Type some text using your keyboard. " +
   "The keys you press will be highlighed and the text will be displayed.");
  context2 = new JLabel("\nNote: Clicking the buttons with your mouse will not perform any action.");
  context1.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14));
  context2.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14));
  top = new JPanel();
  top.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
  middle = new JPanel();
  bottom = new JPanel();
  contextBox = new JPanel();
  __init__layout(top, middle, bottom, contextBox);
  top.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  bottom.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
  top.add(context1);
  top.add(context2);
  middle.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  middle.add(body, BorderLayout.WEST);
  middle.add(body, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 }

 public void __init__() {
  // text area
  __init__body();
  // panels for layout
  __init__panels();
  pack();
  // get length of row strings
  int length_rowOne = rowOne.length;
  int length_rowTwo = rowTwo.length;
  int length_rowThree = rowThree.length;
  int length_rowFour = rowFour.length;
  int length_rowFive = rowFive.length;
  // create array for each row of buttons
  buttons_rowOne = new JButton[length_rowOne];
  buttons_rowTwo = new JButton[length_rowTwo];
  buttons_rowThree = new JButton[length_rowThree];
  buttons_rowFour = new JButton[length_rowFour];
  buttons_rowFive = new JButton[length_rowFive];
  // create panel for each row of buttons
  JPanel r1 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowOne));
  JPanel r2 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowTwo));
  JPanel r3 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowThree));
  JPanel r4 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowFour));
  JPanel r5 = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, length_rowFive));
  // draw out the rows of buttons
  draw(r1, length_rowOne, r2, length_rowTwo, r3, length_rowThree, r4, length_rowFour, r5, length_rowFive);

 }

 // draw rows of buttons
 public void draw(JPanel r1, int s1, JPanel r2, int s2, JPanel r3, int s3, JPanel r4, int s4, JPanel r5, int s5) {
  for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowOne[i]);
   currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
   buttons_rowOne[i] = currentButton;
   r1.add(buttons_rowOne[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < s2; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowTwo[i]);
   currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
   buttons_rowTwo[i] = currentButton;
   r2.add(buttons_rowTwo[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < s3; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowThree[i]);
   currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
   buttons_rowThree[i] = currentButton;
   r3.add(buttons_rowThree[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < s4; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowFour[i]);
   currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
   buttons_rowFour[i] = currentButton;
   r4.add(buttons_rowFour[i]);
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < s5; i++) {
   JButton currentButton = new JButton(rowFive[i]);
   // account for space bar
   if (i == 1) {
    currentButton = new JButton(rowFive[i]);
    currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 10));
    currentButton.setBounds(10, 10, 600, 100);
    buttons_rowFive[i] = currentButton;
   } else {
    currentButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
    buttons_rowFive[i] = currentButton;
   }
   r5.add(buttons_rowFive[i]);
  }
  bottom.add(r1);
  bottom.add(r2);
  bottom.add(r3);
  bottom.add(r4);
  bottom.add(r5);
 } // !draw(...)
 // called when a button is pressed

 @Override
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent press) {
  Object current = press.getSource();
  for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
   if (current.toString() == rowOne[i]) {
    buttons_rowOne[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    repaint();
   } else if (current.toString() == rowTwo[i]) {
    buttons_rowTwo[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    repaint();
   } else if (current.toString() == rowThree[i]) {
    buttons_rowThree[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    repaint();
   } else if (current.toString() == rowFour[i]) {
    buttons_rowFour[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    repaint();
   } else if (current.toString() == rowFive[i]) {
    buttons_rowFive[i].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    repaint();
   }
  }
 } // !keyPressed(...)
 // called when a button is released

 @Override
 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent release) {
  Object current = release.getSource();
  for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
   if (current.toString() == rowOne[i]) {
    buttons_rowOne[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
    repaint();
   } else if (current.toString() == rowTwo[i]) {
    buttons_rowTwo[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
    repaint();
   } else if (current.toString() == rowThree[i]) {
    buttons_rowThree[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
    repaint();
   } else if (current.toString() == rowFour[i]) {
    buttons_rowFour[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
    repaint();
   } else if (current.toString() == rowFive[i]) {
    buttons_rowFive[i].setBackground(defaultColor);
    repaint();
   }
  }
 } // !keyReleased(...)

 @Override
 public void keyTyped(KeyEvent typed) {
  // Object current = typed.getSource().toString();
  // StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  // for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++) {
  //   if (current == rowOne[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   } else if (current == rowTwo[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   } else if (current == rowThree[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   } else if (current == rowFour[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   } else if (current == rowFive[i]) {
  //     sb.append(typed.getKeyCode());
  //     body.append(sb.toString());
  //   }
  // }      
 }
 // main method
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  new ButtonInPane();
 } // !main method

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 999;
} // !main class
```

Comment: "How do I map the physicals key pressed with the on screen keyboard with KeyEvent?" This would make it off topic. Is your code currently working as intended?

Comment: Links can go blant, I edited the full code in. Please also take note that we are very pedantic about code here. Your abreviated version had different formatting applied: `rowOne[]` was on a single line, whereas the pastebin version has it in several lines. This might be something a code reviewer would like to discuss.

Comment: No it is not, I was referred here to CR from SO because it compiles and runs but doesn't work as intended. I made an edit with all of the code. Im trying to ensure that with each physical key press, the respective on-screen key gets its background changed once, and on release changed again.

Comment: Code Review is a community where programmers peer-review your **working** code.This is off topic on Code-Review, I don't get why you got sent here for.

Comment: It's unfortunate that you have been misguided by a user of [so]. To quote [our help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask): "_Code Review is for open-ended questions about code that already works correctly (to the best of your knowledge)._" Sorry, code that merely compiles but does not work as intended does not qualify. =( You question here will likely get closed. Asking on [so] was the right choice. Good luck. Feel free to come back when your code is working to find out how to improve it even more. =)

Comment: @Ludisposed well, what did you expect from [780 rep](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51618117)? ;)